# How to download Parse.com file type using REST API?

Tags: ios, rest, parse-platform

The Parse.com REST API documentation lists many ways of interacting with Parse.com data, such as uploading and downloading classes. It also describes uploading files. But it does not mention how to download a file from Parse.com. Does anyone know if this is possible, and if so, how to do it?

The Parse.com REST API docs are here: [Parse.com REST API](https://www.parse.com/docs/rest)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you query for a class that has a `file` column, Parse will respond with an array of objects which match this query. The `file` column will be in the following format:

{
    "url": "https://files.parse.com/.../hello.txt",
    "name": "...hello.txt"
  }

The `url` key contains the file's url, which is all you need to download the file.

Comment: Hector, I just realized that your answer did not solve my question and I was wondering if you could take a second thought. My question was to specifically use rest because I am planning on adding parse support for a popular open source framework and I don't want to add the entire parse framework. I just want to add file download support.

Comment: Once you have the url, you can use a http connection to download the file. The answer depends on the actual framework/language you're using. For example, you could use the wget command line utility to download this file, or httparty in Ruby, and so on.

Comment: Haha... I re-read your answer and realized that you actually DID answer my question. You were referring to a REST response -- that "Parse will respond with an array of objects... with a file column" that has the url. This makes sense to me! Thanks.

Comment: but this URL also downloads header part as well and that makes image files useless, how to get rid of it any idea @EdwardChin

Comment: Can you post an example of code to use the URL? @HectorRamos