# Download file through REST API

Tags: parse-platform, download

I can not install any sdk in my project.
 Is there a way to download a file(e.g. image,sound) from Parse.com, working only through REST API?

Answer (score 1):

It seems this question has already been answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907562/how-to-download-parse-com-file-type-using-rest-api)

When you query for a class that has a file column, Parse will respond with an array of objects which match this query. The file column will be in the following format:

{ "url": "https://files.parse.com/.../hello.txt", "name": "...hello.txt" }